# Java applet will not display in html file

Tags: java, html, swing, japplet

I am about ready to throw my computer through a wall. I have both the files saved to my desktop. Any help with why this code will not display the java applet would be amazing. Thank You

Html Code

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code= "Test.class" width="400" height="400">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class Test extends JApplet{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3958434285673728601L;

 public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
     g.drawString("Hello World", 25, 25);
 }

public static long getSerialversionuid1() {
     return serialVersionUID;
 }


 }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to learn a dead technology?

Comment: Have you enabled Java in your browser?  Also, have you compiled your class?  You mention "both files", but you should also have Test.class.

Comment: If this one is dead what should i be using?

Comment: FYI: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: *"If this one is dead what should i be using?"* That would depend on what you are hoping to achieve. If you want to display this kind of thing on the web, then you should be using html5, JavaScript and CSS. If you don't care, then you should be starting with a `JPanel` which is added to an instance of a `JFrame` using Swing or JavaFX - Applets are ALWAYS a bad place to start, they have so many little "gotchas" it's simply not worth the time and effort when you're getting started

Comment: whenever I use the object or embed tags it just downloads the files rather than opening them on the screen

Comment: If you do end up throwing your computer through a wall, please post the questions about fixing it to SuperUser http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Applets are a dead technology. You're wasting your time learning them. Oracle [has deprecated](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) them.

Instead, I would focus your time on learning HTML5 and JavaScript. Perhaps "Head First HTML5 Programming" to start.

Answer (score -1):

Applet tag is deprecated in html5 and will not support on  Google Chrome. Use  `<embed>` or `<object>` instead.

Comment: *"Applet tag is deprecated in html5 and will not support on Google Chrome."* The `applet` tag was deprecated in HTML 4.01. *"Use  `<embed>` or `<object>` instead."* Umm.. no. Chrome did not just remove support for the `applet` element/tag but for the entire Java Plug-In. See the links in 1st comment of @MadProgrammer for details.